# What word is the opposite of "plagiarism", trying to pass off your own work as that of others?

Tags: single-word-requests, literature, plagiarism

Assume that I'm citing a piece of poetry and I claim that it's from Shakespeare, when in fact it's my own. Is there a term for that? I'm interested in this exact meaning of a word "opposite" to plagiarism, not in a word for being original or being a donor for plagiarism.

Comment: False attribution?

Comment: Are you doing it in order to heighten its desirability? If so, [passing off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pass%20off#legalDictionary) may fit. Could you edit the question to include **why** you want your work to be thought of as Shakespeare's?

Comment: Fraud is probably what you're looking for, but let me know if there's a better word.

Comment: The single-word request tag "is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Answer (score 7):

A piece of art passed off as a Picasso would be a fake, a forgery, or imitation. Fake money that pretends to be real is called counterfeit, as are Louis Vuitton handbags made on the cheap in Vietnam. 
So I think *literary* (or poetic) *forgery* or *counterfeit* should do the job. [*Literary hoax*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ern_Malley) or *deliberate misattribution* might be other useful terms.

Answer (score 4):

The word pseudepigraphon, plural pseudepigrapha, is a word meaning spurious writings falsely and deliberately attributed to a well-known person, usually from the past, usually in order to claim authority or credence for what is being said.

It is used particularly to refer to certain specific documents which state that they were written by an Old Testament prophet, or a Christian apostle,  but which scholars and the Churches generally,  do not believe were written by them.

This article [Detecting pseudepigraphic texts using novel similarity measures](https://academic.oup.com/dsh/article-abstract/doi/10.1093/llc/fqx011/3077165/Detecting-pseudepigraphic-texts-using-novel?redirectedFrom=PDF) is about a method of detecting these, with particular application to detecting plays which could be falsely attributed to Shakespeare.

There doesn't see to be an associated "ism" though.

Comment: Would the OP be committing _pseudepigraphy_ by deliberately and falsely attributing her poem to Shakespeare? ;-)

Comment: Wikipedia covers this well.

Answer (score -1):

**Anonymity**

Plagiarism is secretly to take someone else's work and to publish it it, meanwhile being silent about the fact that it is not original to oneself.

So the *opposite* action is to donate work to someone else, secretly.

> In which case the opposite of 'plagiarism' is 'anonymity' or 'anonymous charity'.